# How to force/format two decimal places

Tags: x++

Is there a way in x++ 2012. that i can force two decimal places to .00 even if it is a whole number. so 400 would be 400.00

I was using this conversion.

```
num2str0(amount, 0, 2, 1,0)
```

It works fine if there is a decimal but if not, just outputs 400 for example.

Comment: Have you tried num2str? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa866120.aspx

Comment: yes i already tried taht

Comment: Where do you see the 400, in Excel? Show your code.

Comment: yes when it is outputted to csv format.

I put them into a container and then output it     file.writeExp(record)